Hibernatesearch Elasticbackend Projection issue
these are my projection records
@ProjectionConstructor
public record Doctor(
    UUID id,
    @ObjectProjection(includeDepth = 1) DoctorDetails doctorDetails,
    @ObjectProjection(includeDepth = 2) List<DoctorSpecialty> doctorSpecialties
) {}

,
public record DoctorSpecialty(
    UUID id,
    @ObjectProjection(includeDepth = 1) Specialty specialtyCode,
    @ObjectProjection(includeDepth = 1) Doctor doctor
) {}

and
public record Specialty(
    UUID id,
    String specialtyName,
    Integer specilalty
) {}

and this is how I am writing my query
List<com.platform.service.projection.dto.Doctor> suppliers = searchSession
            .search(com.platform.domain.Doctor.class)
            .select(com.platform.service.projection.dto.Doctor.class)
            .where(/* where conditions */)
            .fetchAll();

and I am getting the pollowing error displayed when queried for:
HSEARCH400655: Invalid cardinality for projection on field 'doctorSpecialties.specialtyCode.id': the projection is single-valued, 
but this field is effectively multi-valued in this context, because parent object field 'doctorSpecialties' is multi-valued. Either call '.multi()' when you create the projection on 
field 'doctorSpecialties.specialtyCode.id', or wrap that projection in an object projection like this: 
'f.object("doctorSpecialties").from(<the projection on field doctorSpecialties.specialtyCode.id>).as(...).multi()'.  

      

Hibernate ORM version: 6.5.3.Final and
Hibernate Search Version: 7.2.1.Final
